# "hdfs: command not found" when trying to execute command "hdfs namenode -format" during hadoop installation

Tags: java, python, hadoop

Complete error statement :

```
No command 'hdfs' found, did you mean:
  Command 'hfs' from package 'hfsutils-tcltk' (universe)
  Command 'hdfls' from package 'hdf4-tools' (universe)
  hdfs: command not found
```

Comment: Can you link us to the product you're trying to install? What OS are you using? Have you installed all per-requisites?

Comment: you need to provide more info.

Answer (score 3):

There may be something wrong with your HDFS installation, try giving the full path to hdfs in your command.

```
/path/to/dir/hdfs namenode -format
```

the path depends on your OS and hadoop distribution you're using etc. Use `locate` or `find` for it.

If it works with full path, its probably a PATH issue, export the path in your `.bashrc` and then try.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

try with bin/hdfs instead of hdfs. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have added your hadoop executables to PATH properly.

add the below given export commands in .bashrc if not:

export HADOOP_INSTALL=/path/where/hadoop/is/installed

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"

Finally source the bashrc file

Comment: This worked in my case, I had all of these except PATH exports. Thank you Immanuel

Answer (score 1):

Prepend with Hadoop or HDFS complete path.

check Hadoop/HDFS path by

```
which hadoop
```

or

```
which hdfs
```

then run hdfs command as below.
For eg. running CLI command in Python3.6 script

```
subprocess.run(["/opt/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfs -put <source_file_path> <HDFS_destination_folder_path>"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this error is resolved by now, but this error occurs because the hdfs path may not be set, so first check hdfs path by using this command,

> which hdfs

if path is not set, then check the environment variable in ~/.bash_profile 
if it PATH is written like this,

> PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

change it to this
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

> source ~/.bash_profile

then check the your hdfs path, if it is set by using which command(as shown above)
Then your problem might get resolved.
Hope this helps!